# Any smart ideas on finding the area of this shaded region?

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics, puzzle, area

[image]

Don't let the simplicity of this diagram **fool** you. I have been wondering about this for quite some time, but I can't think of an **easy**/smart way of finding it.

**Any ideas?**

---

*For **reference**, the **Area** is:*

$$\bbox[10pt, border:2pt solid grey]{90−18.75\pi−25\cdot \arctan\left(\frac 12\right)}$$

Comment: If you consider integration as "easy". Then the area is just half of the area of rectangle minus area of circles, then subtract the little white area (calculate using integration) from that.

Comment: $$\dfrac{\text{Area}_{\square} - 2 \text{Area}_{\circ}}{2}$$

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo If you mean (area of the rectangle minus area of the two disks) halved, then that would be incorrect because the lower left corner is not shaded.

Comment: @arctictern Good point. I hadn't noticed it. In any case, it should be easy to find the area of that *unshaded* region using integration.

Comment: What is the source of the image/problem?

Comment: @Bubububu Would you also label using integration in this case as "smart"? :)

Comment: @TheArtist I would say that it is standard. But Blue 's answer is probably smarter.

Comment: @MarkS. I found this link https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-area-of-the-shaded-part where the same problem is discussed

Comment: It looks like the top right is the hard part.

Comment: @arctic tern  that is the right side not left.

Comment: @WaqarAhmad The lower *left* corner is not shaded.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

[image]

We observe that $\triangle PRT$ can be partitioned into five congruent sub-triangles. Therefore, the entire shaded region has area given by ...
$$\begin{align}
3 u + |\text{region}\; PAT| &= 3u + |\square OAPT| - |\text{sector}\;OAT| \\[6pt]
&= 3u + \frac{3}{5}\,|\triangle PRT| - |\text{sector}\;OAT| \\[6pt]
&= 3\cdot\frac{1}{4} r^2 \left( 4 - \pi \right) \;+\; \frac{3}{5}\cdot r^2 \;-\; \frac{1}{2}r^2\cdot 2\theta
\end{align}$$
Since $\theta = \operatorname{atan}\frac{1}{2}$, this becomes

> $$r^2\left(\; \frac{18}{5} -  \frac{3}{4}\pi - \operatorname{atan}\frac{1}{2} \;\right) \qquad\stackrel{r=5}{\to}\qquad
> 90 - \frac{75}{4}\pi - 25\;\operatorname{atan}\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Beautiful and instructive! (+1)

Comment: @MarkusScheuer: Thanks. I actually like this one enough that I posted it to my [trigonography](http://trigonography.com/2016/07/30/two-circles-puzzle/) site. :)

Comment: Nice  examples and presentation on your site. One extra plus. :-)

Comment: "We observe..." (after thinking about it for a day or so) "...that $\triangle PRT$ can be partitioned..." - very pretty, well done.

Comment: @Joffan: *It’s worth recalling the story of the very famous mathematician G.H. Hardy, who in a lecture said about some detail in a proof: “This is obvious.” After a pause, he went on: “Hmm, is it really obvious?” After another pause he left the room to consider the point, returning 20 minutes later with the verdict: “Yes, I was right, it is obvious.” —J.R. Partington* (via [DavidMarcus.com's Math Jokes page](http://www.davidmarcus.com/Humor/MathJokes.htm)) Incidentally, the above was my *third pass* at this problem. (My second is in the edit history.) :)

Comment: I know and love that story. I had a lecturer who had a go-to phrase of  "this result is trivial", so we would write down results with the acronym "pbt", meaning "proof by triviality".

Comment: Awesome! How did you notice the 5 congruent triangles? Wow! Love this answer!

Comment: @TheArtist: Long story. My 2nd attempt (see edit history) noted that $|PA| = |PR|/5$, which seemed significant to me. Then Christian posted an answer that inspired me to look at the larger shaded area. Eventually, various fifths-of-$r^2$ triangle areas I was encountering suggested that I could/should be conveying their sizes visually, without so darned much algebraic manipulation. (After all, visualization is supposed to be [my thing](http://trigonography.com)!) The full dissection revealed itself after a couple of "obvious" cuts. I was pleasantly surprised by how neatly it all worked-out. :)

Comment: @TheArtist: Thanks for the bounty! :)  By the way ... Where did you get this puzzle? I want to give proper credit on my site.

Comment: How do you get that kind of pictures? Very nice. Visio?

Comment: @JimThio: Thanks. I use [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org).

Answer (score 25):

[**Note:** [My second answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1875751/409) is much better.]

I'll focus on the *unshaded* region at the bottom-left.

[image]

By an aspect of the [Inscribed Angle Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle#Theorem), we know that $\angle AOB = 2\;\angle ABP$ (justifying marking these $\theta$ and $2\theta$). By a related result, we have that
$$\phi = \frac{1}{2}\left(\angle BOC - \angle AOB\right) = 45^\circ - \theta$$
Moreover, we know that 
$$\phi = \operatorname{atan}\frac{1}{2} \approx 26.56^\circ \qquad\to\qquad \theta = 45^\circ - \operatorname{atan}\frac{1}{2} \approx 18.43^\circ$$

From here, knowing the circle's radius, one may calculate the lower-left area as ...
$$\begin{align}
&|\triangle PAB| + |\triangle OAB| - |\text{sector } OAB| \\
\end{align}$$
... from which we readily derive the area in the original question. For now, I'll leave these details to the reader.

Comment: What software do you use to draw figures? It's beautiful.

Comment: @theartist Geogebra is free and makes it easy to make things like this.

Comment: @MarkS. Thanks a lot mark :)

Comment: Does the theorem need to be invoked? You have an isosceles triangle so the angles OAB and OBA must be 90 - theta. PB is a tangent and OB is a radius so perpendicular. So ABP is theta.

Comment: @Carlos: You've basically explained *why* the "tangent" case of the IAT works, so it doesn't really matter whether one invokes the IAT or makes that argument explicitly. Be that as it may ... I use the related angle-subtraction result to calculate $\phi$, so invoking IAT first helps set the conceptual mood. (Note: the related result isn't entirely necessary here, either. We have $\angle ACB = \theta$ (it's an inscribed angle), and thus that $\angle OPC = \theta$ (alternate interior angles), which in turn gives $\theta + \phi = 45^\circ$. I wonder if that's a "better" way to think about this.)

Comment: Another way to find φ, perhaps a little longer but using very elementary steps: OAC = OCA = φ (by internal angles of an isosceles tri, then by alternating angles); also CAB = φ + θ (by running a horizontal line through A); so OAC = 2φ + θ, and so summing the internal angles of the triangle OAC, we get 180° = (2θ) + (2φ + θ) + (2φ + θ) = 4φ + 4θ.

Answer (score 20):

Put $\arctan{1\over2}=:\alpha$. Then $$\sin(2\alpha)={2\tan\alpha\over1+\tan^2\alpha}={4\over5}\ .$$ The area $A$ in question consists of three "arrow heads" plus the area shaded in the following figure. The latter is a right triangle minus a sector and a smaller triangle. We therefore obtain
$$A={3\over4}(10^2- 25\pi)+{25\over2}\bigl(2-2\alpha-\sin(2\alpha)\bigr)=90-{75\over4}\pi-25\alpha\ .$$

[image]

Comment: Clever approach. Nice and concise! (+1)

Answer (score 14):

The big black roundy-corner on the bottom right has area $(10^2 - \pi\cdot 5^2)/4$ and there are 3 complete copies of it and one copy trimmed by a small roundy-triangle. We will focus on this roundy-triangle which is the same as the one in the bottom left.

So the key is to compute the area of the small white roundy-triangle at the bottom left.

To this end we must find the intersection of the diagonal and the circle that create the top of this triangle.

The equation of the circle and of the diagonal are 
$$
y = 1/2 x \\
(x-5)^2 + (y-5)^2 = 25
$$
Solving that with [WA](http://tinyurl.com/hn4whly) gives : $x=2,\ y=1$.

So now we can decompose this roundy-triangle into two parts by drawing a vertical line that goes through this intersection. This gives a true triangle (the left part) which has area $1$ and another roundy-triangle (the right part).

To compute the area of the roundy-right-triangle, we can use integration :
$$
\int_2^5 -\sqrt{25 - (x-5)^2} + 5\  dx
$$
See [WA](http://tinyurl.com/zdomcpy) for the plot of this function.

Answer (score 11):

[image]

Considering the right triangle with legs $1-s\sin(\theta)$ and $1-s\cos(\theta)$, we have
$$
1=(1-s\cos(\theta))^2+(1-s\sin(\theta))^2\tag{1}
$$
Solving for $s$, we get
$$
s=\sin(\theta)+\cos(\theta)-\sqrt{2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)}\tag{2}
$$
Setting $t=\tan(\theta)$ yields
$$
\begin{align}
s\sin(\theta)&=\frac{t}{1+t^2}\left(t-\sqrt{2t}+1\right)\\
s\cos(\theta)&=\frac{1}{1+t^2}\left(t-\sqrt{2t}+1\right)\\
\tan(\phi/2)&=\frac{1-s\cos(\theta)}{2-s\sin(\theta)}
\end{align}\tag{3}
$$
Setting $\tan(\theta)=\frac12$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
s\sin(\theta)&=\frac15\\
s\cos(\theta)&=\frac25\\
\tan(\phi/2)&=\frac13
\end{align}\tag{4}
$$
The area of the green piece is
$$
\frac\phi2-\frac12(1-s\cos(\theta))=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac13\right)-\frac3{10}\tag{5}
$$
The sum of the areas of the purple and green pieces is
$$
\frac12s\sin(\theta)=\frac1{10}\tag{6}
$$
Therefore, the area of the purple piece is
$$
\frac25-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac13\right)\tag{7}
$$

---

$(7)$ used a circle with radius $1$. For a circle with radius $5$, we get an area of
$$
10-25\tan^{-1}\left(\frac13\right)\tag{8}
$$
The area of half the $10\times20$ rectangle minus the two circles of radius $5$ is
$$
100-25\pi\tag{9}
$$
Therefore, the area in the given image is the difference of $(9)$ and $(8)$:
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{90+25\tan^{-1}\left(\frac13\right)-25\pi}\tag{10}
$$

---

$(10)$ is a different form of the same area:
$$
\begin{align}
90+25\tan^{-1}\left(\frac13\right)-25\pi
&=90+25\tan^{-1}\left(\frac13\right)-25\tan^{-1}\left(1\right)-\frac{75}4\pi\\
&=90+25\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\frac13-1}{1+\frac13\cdot1}\right)-\frac{75}4\pi\\
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{90-25\tan^{-1}\left(\frac12\right)-\frac{75}4\pi}\tag{11}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 6):

Well, I'm assuming you have problems only with the upper right corner, since the rest is just $\frac 34 (10² - \pi5²)$. I also assume you can calculate the area of the small part of the circle, so we have

$$ A = \frac{5 \cdot 10}2 - A_1$$
$$ A_1 = \pi \cdot 5^2 - \pi \cdot (\frac52)^2 - A_{small}$$

where $A$ is the shaded area we didn't know yet, $A_1$ is the area of the triangle intersected with the circle and $A_{small}$ the area of the small portion of the circle.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

By the look of the answer, it would appear that there is no avoiding calculating the area of the roundy white triangle, or at least indirectly.

Call this area $x$ and the area of the lowest right hand corner region $a$, where $4a=100-25\pi$. Let the area of the smaller segment of the circle be $s$. The chord of this segment subtends an angle $\pi-2\arctan\frac 12$ at the centre of the circle. In which case

$$s=\frac 12\cdot25(\pi-2\arctan\frac 12-\sin(2\arctan\frac 12))$$
$$\Rightarrow s=\frac{25}{2}\pi-25\arctan\frac 12-10$$

Meanwhile, $x=25-a-s$ and the required region is $R=4a-x=5a-25+s$

Substituting in the value of $s$ gives the required answer $$R=90-18.75\pi-25\arctan \frac 12$$

Answer (score 4):

[image: Visual decomposition]

$$\small \begin{align} A_\textsf{Shaded} &= A_\textsf{Square} - \color{darkorange}{A_\textsf{Circle}} - (\color{green}{A_\textsf{4-gon}}+\color{red}{A_\textsf{Triangle}})+\color{blue}{A_\textsf{CircleSegment}}\\&= 10^2 - \color{darkorange}{\pi \times 5^2} - \left(\color{green}{9}+\color{red}{1}\right)+\color{blue}{\frac{\arctan{(3/4)}}{2\pi}\pi \times 5^2} \\ &= 100 - \color{darkorange}{25\pi}-10+\color{blue}{12.5\arctan{\frac {3}{4}}}\\ &\approx 19.504…\end{align}$$

$\blacksquare $

Comment: +1. Interesting. I made multiple passes at this puzzle, and I even saw Christian's answer referencing a sine equal to $4/5$, but I don't think it ever really dawned on me that there was a $3$-$4$-$5$ triangle lurking.

Answer (score 3):

My method is just an ordinary one but it shows how the suggest answer is obtained.

It should be clear that how the lengths and angles are defined as shown.

[image]

$\theta = \tan^{-1}(\dfrac {1}{2})$ in radians.

By power$(A, C_2)$, $z = \dfrac {100}{\sqrt {125}}$. Then, by power $(P, C_3)$, $y = \dfrac {25}{\sqrt {125}}$.

By similar triangles, $t = … = 2$.

After transferring the leftmost black shaded part to its more suitable position (above X), the required area

$= [(10 \times 10) square] - [C_2] - [red]$

$= 100 - 25 \pi - ([purple] - [\dfrac {C_1}{4}] - [yellow])$

$= 100 - 25\pi – 25 + \dfrac {25\pi}{4} + [yellow]$

$= 75 - 18.75\pi + [yellow]$

$= 75 - 18.75\pi + ([⊿XCQ] - [grey])$

$=75 - 18.75\pi + 25 - [grey]$

$= 100 - 18.75\pi - ([⊿XYQ] + [section YPQ] $

$= 100 - 18.75\pi - ([⊿XYQ] + [sector OPQ] $

$= 100 - 18.75\pi - (10 + \dfrac {(25)2\theta}{2})$

$= 90 - 18.75\pi - 25\tan^{-1}(\dfrac {1}{2})$

Comment: which program you used to draw that?

Comment: @SalechAlhasov Create a sketch from Geogebra. Upload it to the clipboard.

Answer (score 2):

If $A=B+X$ where $B=\frac 12+\int_2^5(5-\sqrt{10x-x^2})dx$ (*small white area below the diagonal*) and $X$ the asked area then one has by symmetry $$2A+2(\pi\cdot5^2)=20\cdot 10\iff A+25\cdot\pi=100$$
We have$\int_2^5(5-\sqrt{10x-x^2})dx\approx 0.95624$ so $$X=100-25\cdot\pi-0.5-0.95624\approx 20.003943$$

Answer (score 2):

I posted a solution directly on 9gag:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

"Easy"? What's easy? My math/algebra skills are very rusty, but I'd set the problem up this way:

1. Drop a perpendicular from the intersection of the circle and the straight line.
2. Take the area of the triangle @30 deg.
3. (Moving to the right) Do an integral from the perpendicular to the osculation point on the rectangle given the equation of the circle.
4. Add the two areas: the triangle and the integral

Question is: is doing an integral "easy". Conceptually yes, mathematically ... I don't know. Depends.