# How do I find the area for the shaded area?

Tags: geometry

How do I find the area shaded in red? The difficulty is actually in finding the area in blue.

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of (https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-area-of-the-shaded-part)

Comment: With a little integral calculus the blue part is not that problematic to calculate, imo.: $$\int_0^2\frac x2\,dx+\int_2^5\left(\sqrt{10x-x^2}+5\right)dx\ldots$$

Comment: Duplicate of ["Any smart ideas on finding the area of this shaded region?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1874736/409).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a video on youtube where a guy solves exctly this problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xnE_sO7PbBs&t=2s