# What is the area shaded in this figure?

Tags: geometry

I was sent this problem by a friend, they say it is a year  6 question. Using trigonometry I got the shaded area as  $4 - \frac{\pi}{3}$.

Now Year six, I doubt if they do trigonometry. Is there another approach out there?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure about your answer?  It looks a little large to me.  I would say that using the symmetry of the diagram you should be expecting something like $8-2\pi$.

Comment: Can you provide details about what you'd expect in sixth year? Visitors here come from a wide variety of contries and educational systems. I assume they wouldn't be doing integrals either?

Comment: @MvG, it doesn't matter now as the actual answer is $\frac{32}{5}-4\tan^{-1}(\frac{3}{4})$, and so you can't do it without trigonometry.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1875751/409) finds the area of a related region. In the notation used there, the target area here can be written as $u-|\text{region}PAT|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Diagram]

Label the vertices as shown in the diagram.
$\tan\alpha=\frac{1}{2}\implies \tan 2\alpha=\frac{4}{3}\implies 2\alpha=\tan^{-1}(\frac{4}{3})$

$\therefore$ Area of circular sector$ BAG=8\tan^{-1}(\frac{4}{3})$

Area of $\triangle AGC=16\cos\alpha\sin\alpha=8\sin2\alpha=\frac{32}{5}$

Thus, area of curved figure $BEG=\frac{48}{5}-8\tan^{-1}(\frac{4}{3})$

Therefore, Area of shaded part$=\frac{1}{2}$ (Area of $BEFC$)$-\frac{1}{2}$ (Area of semicircle)$-$Area of curved figure $BEG$.

This gives $\frac{32}{5}-4\pi+8\tan^{-1}(\frac{4}{3})=\frac{32}{5}-4\tan^{-1}(\frac{3}{4})\approx1.252$

Comment: the numerical result is correct, I don't believe other calculation: that of BEG and the last passage where $4\pi$ disappear. I think that BEG=$16-32/5 -8tan^{-1}(4/3)$

Comment: ok, now I understant the last passage: $4/3\to 3/4$ but I still think BEG is wrong

Comment: @user126154 $\frac{\pi}{2}-\tan^{-1}(\frac{4}{3})=\tan^{-1}(\frac{3}{4})$

Comment: @user126154, Thanks. Fixed the typo.

Answer (score 0):

Flip the image by vertically.

It is not as simple as you think.  Year six is probably high school when they can do geometry and calculus.  I have done it using calculus and the area is as shown in the figure
[image]

Comment: It widened my approaches and a fantastic link; thank you all!

Comment: @WaitaraMburu, while one always appreciates if someone benefits from their efforts, it is always good if you upvote and accept an answer(especially answers of new users like me), if you find the answer correct and useful.