# A semicircle is inscribed in a rectangle; find the area bounded by the semicircle and a diagonal.

Tags: geometry

What is the area of the shaded part? A rectangle has semicircle and triangle inside. Find the area.

[image]

Comment: You should show your work, to help us help you.

Comment: time to watch a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Seb863FnfU)

Comment: sorry but that picture  just sent to me , i dont know how to answer it

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1874736/409) asks about a different region (and uses different numbers), but it's strongly related to the one in your question.